# Multi column combobox change width

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have a vb.net combobox with three columns.
How can I make the e.bounds a wider? I want to set the dropdown of the combobox
wider than the actual combobox.

I used the following code :

```
   Private Sub BlokKiesCMB_DrawItem(ByVal sender As 
   System.Object, ByVal e As
   System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs) 
   Handles BlokKiesCMB.DrawItem
    ' Draw the default background
    e.DrawBackground()

    ' The ComboBox is bound to a DataTable,
    ' so the items are DataRowView objects.
    Dim drv As DataRowView = CType(BlokKiesCMB.Items(e.Index), DataRowView)


    ' Retrieve the value of each column.
    Dim blokno As String = drv("blokno").ToString()
    Dim kultivar As String = drv("kultivar").ToString()
    Dim klas As String = drv("klas").ToString()

    ' Get the bounds for the first column

    Dim r1 As Rectangle = e.Bounds
    r1.Width = r1.Width / 3

    ' Draw the text on the first column
    Using sb As SolidBrush = New SolidBrush(e.ForeColor)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(blokno, e.Font, sb, r1)
    End Using

    ' Draw a line to isolate the columns 
    Using p As Pen = New Pen(Color.Black)
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, r1.Right, 0, r1.Right, r1.Bottom)
    End Using

    ' Get the bounds for the second column
    Dim r2 As Rectangle = e.Bounds
    r2.X = e.Bounds.Width / 3
    r2.Width = r2.Width / 3

    ' Draw the text on the second column
    Using sb As SolidBrush = New SolidBrush(e.ForeColor)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(kultivar, e.Font, sb, r2)
    End Using

    ' Draw a line to isolate the columns 
    Using p As Pen = New Pen(Color.Black)
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, r2.Right, 0, r2.Right, r2.Bottom)
    End Using



    ' Get the bounds for the third column
    Dim r3 As Rectangle = e.Bounds
    r3.X = r2.Width + r2.X
    r3.Width = r3.Width / 3



    ' Draw the text on the third column
    Using sb As SolidBrush = New SolidBrush(e.ForeColor)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(klas, e.Font, sb, r3)
    End Using


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.Bounds` does not give you the sides of `ComboBox` or its `DropDown` box. `Bounds` refers to the position of the `ComboBox` relative to its parent. Read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bounds(v=vs.110).aspx) for further reference.

Now, `WinForms` `ComboBox` has a property called `DropDownWidth` which allows you to control the width of the `DropDown` wider than the actual `ComboBox`'s width. This property, by default, is set as the same value as the `ComboBox`'s width.

Here is the actual example, the size of the `ComboBox` is 121, by default the size of its `DropDown` box will be 121 too.

[image]

But if you change the `DropDownWidth` (says, to 200)

```
Me.ComboBox1.DropDownWidth = 200 'change this
```

This is what you are going to get

[image]

The `ComboBox` drop down box got wider.

Comment: Hi Ian. Works great. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you Ian. I will do this in future. Regards